# .htaccess rewrite dynamic url in subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-proxy

I have this url:

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?&location=ca&co=us
```

I would like rewrite so:

```
ca.example.com
```

In htaccess I placed this code but not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/]*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ /search.php?location=$1&co=us [L,P]
```

I dont understand where Im wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back reference from `RewriteCond` is `%1`, `%2` etc. You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.(vincentjob\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%2/search.php?location=%1&co=us [L,P]
```

Assuming `mod_proxy` is setup and running.

Comment: I get mod proxy error. Is there another way to get same result?

Comment: probably I  wrote not correct, I need show content of http://www.example.com/search.php?&location=ca&co=us in subdomain ca.example.com. With your code when I enter in subdomain Im redirect auto in http://www.example.com/search.php?&location=ca&co=us

Comment: Sorry, I have only a little problem: if I have a subdomain with two words (example new york.vincentjob.com) how Can I do?

Comment: how Should I write the subdomain new york.vincentjob.com? With space?

Comment: domain name cannot have spaces. Anyway `.+?` matches anything in my answer.

Comment: right! thanks again anubhava! have you a great time!